Как применить XSLT к XML или HTML?
Есть вот такой код:
from lxml import etree
with open('xslt_orgdo.xsl') as file:
     xslt_root = etree.XML(file.read())

Падает ошибка:
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
Предлагается убрать первую строку либо загружать в bytes.
Вопрос: Как сделать, без удаления этой первой строки?
Т.е. просто загрузить файл XSLT и xml траснформировать.

Вроде как можно использовать кодирование, но как?

Ну, банально дописать 'rb' в функции open?

оо, получилось))

так, а если мне нужно это сделать со строкой?

допустим я в response = post(**args) получаю ответ в виде xml. Достать его можно вроде так: response.text. И вот как этот текст переделать в binary?

response.content тогда

спасибо большое!

Блин, это не поможет, т.к. нужен binary, а там bytes.

Что такое «нужен binary»? Где кому зачем нужен?

если открыть help(open) то флаг b это binary mode

я кажется нашёл в чем проблема, похоже дело в кодировке. т.к. если я создал xml файл с тем же содержимым и положу его в etree.XML то всё норм. А вот если я это сделаю из response.content то ошибка

т.е. вот так: etree.XML(response.content) ошибка: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 

если читаю тоже самое с флагом b, предварительно сохранив через vscode, то всё норм

Какая ошибка? Вы скопировали самую бесполезную строчку из текста ошибки

>>> etree.XML(report_response.content) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3286, in lxml.etree.XML   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1989, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseDoc   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1164, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 743, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult 

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 672, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError   File "<string>", line 8 lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: attributes construct error, line 8, column 114 

Ну значит видимо внутри content что-то не то, смотрите что конкретно там

Нашёл ошибку. Ошибка была на внешней системе. Т.е. внешняя система формирует наименование поля с кавычками внутри наименования. Например Компания ООО "Рога и копыта". И валидацию такой xml не проходил. Блин он ведь ещё написал строка 8 символ 114. @andreymal Спасибо за ответы!
